# Add/Remove Items from Mat Chip List using User Input

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material

I am trying to use angular.material.io to create a dropdown header that adds/removes material chips to a displayed list when selected. These will be used to filter eventually, but not in the example code.

We want to:

- add a chip by selecting the option from dropdown
- add a chip by typed user input (and also selecting the relevant option in process)
- remove a chip by unselecting from the dropdown
- unselect an option from dropdown when the relevant chip is removed

Currently, we can add chips both ways but a typed user input does not select the relevant option. We can also remove a chip by clicking the X, but it does not remove it from the dropdown list.

The main problem is that the checkboxes are unaffected by anything except direct selection, I cannot get the chip list to work with the dropdown.

Here is an example code base:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9rnfbc